# SDL2 access violation error whilst initializing window

Tags: c++, sdl-2

We've just started learning how to work with SDL2 and whilst following a tutorial we ran into this access violation error. We're trying to initialize a green window. We're familiar with C and C#, but we haven't got much experience with C++.

Whilst messing around we determined that one of the last four lines seemed to contain the problem. We hope someone can help.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF801C69BB9 (SDL2.dll) in PWS.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000000000FF.

```c
#include "SDL.h"
#undef main

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_GetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, (uint8_t*)255, 0, (uint8_t*)255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the cause of your crash, but you are not handling `main` the way SDL expects: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady

Comment: Note that many SDL calls can fail, but you are not checking for those failure cases.  See the docs for [`SDL_GetError`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError) for an example.

Comment: Is that `#undef main` some SDL magic? It looks scary...

Comment: @TedLyngmo SDL does `#define main` so that it can bookend some stuff around it, but `#undef`'ing it is not the correct way to circumvent that (see the link in my comment for more info on that).

Answer (score 3):

The crash you are seeing comes from the following line:

```
SDL_GetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, (uint8_t*)255, 0, (uint8_t*)255);
```

The fact that you had to cast the color value to a pointer is an immediate clue that something wrong is going on here.

[`SDL_GetRenderDrawColor()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRenderDrawColor) (notice the **Get**) writes the current value of the render color to the addresses passed as arguments, so you are asking SDL to write the red and blue components of the current color to the `0` memory address, and the green and alpha components to the `255` memory address. These will result in an **Access Violation**, since `0` and `255` are not valid memory addresses to write at.

`255` in 64-bit hexadecimal is `0x00000000000000FF` which happens to be exactly what the error is telling you the invalid writing location is. This is why I can be so confident that this specific line is the culprit.

N.B. SDL is probably skipping over the writes to `0`, as `0` meaning nowhere is a common convention.

You probably meant to use [`SDL_SetRenderDrawColor()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderDrawColor) instead:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);
```

However, there's at least one other major problem in your program: You are not setting up your `main()` function the way SDL expects. If you *HAVE* to circumvent SDL taking over the main function, you should use [`SDL_SetMainReady()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!!